# PayPal error messages on PHP 5.3.1

Tags: php, paypal

I'm integrating PayPal in an application written in PHP and running on PHP 5.3.1 (using Zend Engine 2.3.0).
Every time I require a PayPal SDK file or use any of the methods it prints out an enormous amount of error and warning messages.
I obviously want to keep error message reporting at the maximum level possible (at least for my code).

My problem is similar to this one (I didn't write that) https://www.x.com/message/167121#167121

I'm concerned with possible security issues and with the obvious annoying amount of messages going into the log.

Do you have any idea of how to fix/work around this?

Thanks :)

EDIT:
A sample from the warning list (there are more):

As an example (but there are more):

> Strict Standards: Assigning the return
>   value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in (...)/PayPal.php on line
>   87
>
> Strict Standards: Assigning the return
>   value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in (...)/PayPal.php on line
>   115
>
> Strict Standards: Declaration of
>   PayPal::raiseError() should be
>   compatible with that of
>   PEAR::raiseError() in (...)/PayPal.php
>   on line 198
>
> Strict Standards: Assigning the return
>   value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in (...)/PayPal/Hack.php on
>   line 78
>
> Strict Standards: Assigning the return
>   value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in
>   (...)/PayPal/SOAP/Value.php on line 90
>
> Strict Standards: Assigning the return
>   value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in
>   (...)/PayPal/SOAP/Value.php on line 93
>
> Strict Standards: Assigning the return
>   value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in
>   (...)/PayPal/SOAP/Base.php on line 221
>
> Strict Standards: Assigning the return
>   value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in
>   (...)/PayPal/SOAP/Base.php on line 514
>
> Strict Standards: Assigning the return
>   value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in
>   (...)/PayPal/SOAP/Base.php on line 616
>
> Strict Standards: Assigning the return
>   value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in
>   (...)/PayPal/SOAP/Base.php on line 617
>
> Strict Standards: Assigning the return
>   value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in
>   (...)/PayPal/SOAP/Base.php on line 760
>
> Strict Standards: Assigning the return
>   value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in
>   (...)/PayPal/SOAP/Base.php on line 897
>
> Strict Standards: Assigning the return
>   value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in
>   (...)/PayPal/SOAP/Base.php on line
>   1055
>
> Strict Standards: Assigning the return
>   value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in
>   (...)/PayPal/SOAP/Base.php on line
>   1083
>
> Strict Standards: Assigning the return
>   value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in
>   (...)/PayPal/SOAP/Base.php on line
>   1109
>
> Strict Standards: Assigning the return
>   value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in
>   (...)/PayPal/SOAP/Base.php on line
>   1151
>
> Strict Standards: Assigning the return
>   value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in
>   (...)/PayPal/SOAP/Base.php on line
>   1176
>
> Strict Standards: Assigning the return
>   value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in
>   (...)/PayPal/Type/XSDType.php on line
>   97
>
> Strict Standards: Assigning the return
>   value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in
>   (...)/PayPal/Type/XSDType.php on line
>   110
>
> Strict Standards: Assigning the return
>   value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in
>   (...)/PayPal/Type/XSDType.php on line
>   112
>
> Strict Standards: Assigning the return
>   value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in
>   (...)/PayPal/Profile/Handler/Array.php
>   on line 53
>
> Strict Standards: Assigning the return
>   value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in
>   (...)/PayPal/Profile/API.php on line
>   256
>
> Strict Standards: Assigning the return
>   value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in
>   (...)/PayPal/Type/XSDSimpleType.php on
>   line 69
>
> Strict Standards: Assigning the return
>   value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in
>   (...)/PayPal/Type/XSDSimpleType.php on
>   line 71
>
> Strict Standards: Assigning the return
>   value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in
>   (...)/PayPal/Type/XSDSimpleType.php on
>   line 98
>
> Strict Standards: Assigning the return
>   value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in
>   (...)/PayPal/Type/XSDSimpleType.php on
>   line 111
>
> Strict Standards: Assigning the return
>   value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in
>   (...)/PayPal/Type/XSDSimpleType.php on
>   line 113

Comment: We can't provide effective help without seeing the actual error messages you're getting.  Just saying that the errors are *like* errors others are seeing on another site doesn't mean that those are the same exact errors you're having, nor does it mean that the solution is the same.  If you can copy and paste a few of your errors, we'll help you track them down (or, given the answer from the PayPal rep in that linked forum post, help you determine if the errors are worth hiding instead).

Comment: I'm going to answer on the main thread because of the character limit.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that PayPal Code is an external library from the PEAR Package your using that isn't 5.3 Strict comparable. There quite some Code that suffers from that Problem.

Assuming you don't want to change that Code and Submit it back ( ;) ) there aren't so many things you can do.

To name the first two that come to mind:

In your wrapper Code for the Paypal access turn of E_STRICT everytime before the call and back on after.
E.g.

```
<?php
class myPayPalWrapper { 
    public function doX() { 
         $x = error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_STRICT); # or something
         $this->externalPaypalClass->doX();
         error_reporting($x);
    }
}
```

doesn't look really pretty and requires a good amount of code.

If your are already using a custom errorhandler in your project you could extend that to filter out all errors of that lib.
E.g.

```
<?php
function myErrorHandler($iErrno, $sErrstr, $sErrfile, $iErrline) {
    if(error_reporting() & $iErrno) {
        if(strpos("libFolder/paypal", $sErrfile) !== false) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: +1 for the turn-off-strict wrapper for ugly third-party code.

Comment: That's great! :) We're using the first option but the second sounds more reasonable :)

Thanks