# is there any known issue with php 5.3 that prevent php SDK from working?

Tags: php, sdk, paypal

I had to integrate Paypal Payment pro to a client's site. i started by installing paypal php SDK on my server. which runs on php 5.2.17 and seems to work perfect.

When i was done testing i moved the SDK from my server to my client server which runs php 5.3.2 and for some reason it doesn't work.

At start we was sure it was permission issue because the script couldn't write to paypal.log file

For about a week now we are working with the hosting company to solve the problem.
One idea was to roll the server back to 5.2.17(to mach my server's php version). this change fixed the issue however other websites on the server got screwed which forced us to go back to 5.3.2

I've been searching around for solutions. one solution I've found here at:
[PayPal error messages on PHP 5.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345458/paypal-error-messages-on-php-5-3-1)
was related to pear packages.

Anyone knows if there's any special pear packages needed in order for the SDK to work ?

Here is some technical information:

I get the following errors when i try the doDirectPayment sample when error-reporting is set to -1

**5 or 6 of those:**

`Warning: error_log(../PayPal.log) [function.error-log]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/brando/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ownapainting-shopping-cart/paypal/lib/PPLoggingManager.php on line 60`

**1 of:**

`Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /home/brando/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ownapainting-shopping-cart/paypal/lib/PPUtils.php on line 99`

**About 12 of those:**

`Strict Standards: Non-static method PPUtils::convertXmlObjToArr() should not be called statically in /home/brando/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ownapainting-shopping-cart/paypal/lib/PPUtils.php on line 99`

**and 2 of 5hose:**

`Notice: Class string not found. in /home/brando/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ownapainting-shopping-cart/paypal/lib/PPXmlMessage.php on line 172`

**The request:**

`<soapenv:Envelope  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  xmlns:ns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI" xmlns:ebl="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xmlns:cc="urn:ebay:apis:CoreComponentTypes" xmlns:ed="urn:ebay:apis:EnhancedDataTypes" ><soapenv:Header><ns:RequesterCredentials><ebl:Credentials><ebl:Username>yanivk_1359660748_biz_api1.gmail.com</ebl:Username><ebl:Password>1359660807</ebl:Password><ebl:Signature>AYWZfz56bBT.eby8WGW6PcSYJuLGAJAkQp0g-4el58kjzrOUFVSWTpE5</ebl:Signature></ebl:Credentials></ns:RequesterCredentials></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><ns:DoDirectPaymentReq><ns:DoDirectPaymentRequest><ebl:DoDirectPaymentRequestDetails><ebl:PaymentDetails><ebl:OrderTotal><ebl:currencyID>USD</ebl:currencyID><ebl:value>1.00</ebl:value></ebl:OrderTotal><ebl:ShipToAddress><ebl:Name>John Doe</ebl:Name><ebl:Street1>1 Main St</ebl:Street1><ebl:CityName>San Jose</ebl:CityName><ebl:StateOrProvince>CA</ebl:StateOrProvince><ebl:Country>US</ebl:Country><ebl:PostalCode>95131</ebl:PostalCode></ebl:ShipToAddress></ebl:PaymentDetails><ebl:CreditCard><ebl:CreditCardType>Visa</ebl:CreditCardType><ebl:CreditCardNumber>4079305435163119</ebl:CreditCardNumber><ebl:ExpMonth>01</ebl:ExpMonth><ebl:ExpYear>2014</ebl:ExpYear><ebl:CardOwner><ebl:PayerName><ebl:FirstName>John</ebl:FirstName><ebl:LastName>Doe</ebl:LastName></ebl:PayerName><ebl:PayerCountry>US</ebl:PayerCountry><ebl:Address><ebl:Name>John Doe</ebl:Name><ebl:Street1>1 Main St</ebl:Street1><ebl:CityName>San Jose</ebl:CityName><ebl:StateOrProvince>CA</ebl:StateOrProvince><ebl:Country>US</ebl:Country><ebl:PostalCode>95131</ebl:PostalCode></ebl:Address></ebl:CardOwner><ebl:CVV2>962</ebl:CVV2></ebl:CreditCard></ebl:DoDirectPaymentRequestDetails><ebl:Version>94.0</ebl:Version></ns:DoDirectPaymentRequest></ns:DoDirectPaymentReq></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>`

**The response:**

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:cc="urn:ebay:apis:CoreComponentTypes" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:ed="urn:ebay:apis:EnhancedDataTypes" xmlns:ebl="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xmlns:ns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI"><SOAP-ENV:Header><Security xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xsi:type="wsse:SecurityType"></Security><RequesterCredentials xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI" xsi:type="ebl:CustomSecurityHeaderType"><Credentials xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xsi:type="ebl:UserIdPasswordType"><Username xsi:type="xs:string"></Username><Password xsi:type="xs:string"></Password><Signature xsi:type="xs:string"></Signature><Subject xsi:type="xs:string"></Subject></Credentials></RequesterCredentials></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body id="_0"><DoDirectPaymentResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI"><Timestamp xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">2013-02-10T23:51:36Z</Timestamp><Ack xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">Failure</Ack><CorrelationID xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">ccaa89a0e921f</CorrelationID><Errors xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xsi:type="ebl:ErrorType"><ShortMessage xsi:type="xs:string">Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.</ShortMessage><LongMessage xsi:type="xs:string">Order total is invalid.</LongMessage><ErrorCode xsi:type="xs:token">10401</ErrorCode><SeverityCode xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">Error</SeverityCode></Errors><Version xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">94.0</Version><Build xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">5060305</Build><Amount xsi:type="cc:BasicAmountType" currencyID="USD">0.00</Amount></DoDirectPaymentResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>`

I know this is a very specific issue and the likelihood of someone familiar with this issue is low but i had to ask.

Thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address each of these errors:

```
Warning: error_log(../PayPal.log) [function.error-log]: failed to open stream: Permission
denied in /home/brando/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ownapainting-shopping-
cart/paypal/lib/PPLoggingManager.php on line 60
```

This would indicate a permission issue at the said path. Ensure that the file exists and has appropriate permissions for your www-root (or whatever user is running your Apache service).

```
Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in 
/home/brando/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ownapainting-shopping-
cart/paypal/lib/PPUtils.php on line 99
```

This indicates a non-best practice usage of variables. I could go more in depth with this, but basically, something was passed in by reference instead of by value (google it for the difference).

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method PPUtils::convertXmlObjToArr() should not be called 
statically in /home/brando/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ownapainting-shopping-
cart/paypal/lib/PPUtils.php on line 99
```

A static method is a method in a class which can be called without instantiating the entire class. This method appears to have not been defined as static, but is being used as static.

```
Notice: Class string not found. in /home/brando/public_html/wp-
content/plugins/ownapainting-shopping-cart/paypal/lib/PPXmlMessage.php on line 172
```

Another issue with strict standards.

Basically for the last 3, change error reporting from E_STRICT | E_ALL to just E_ALL. It wont fix the issues persay, but it will keep them from appearing to customers.

The ultimate solution is to simply not use the PayPal SDK. It is not recommended that this be used at all really. The SDK causes more issues that anything really. Here is some starter information I give people when they are beginning with their PayPal integration. It should help:

```
Getting Started: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-payments-pro/paypal-payments-pro-getting-started-guide 
API Reference Guide: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api?qt-api_references=1#qt-api_references 
Sample Code: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-code-samples
```

Any please please please use NVP, not SOAP. SOAP is bloated and completely unnecessary.

Comment: nope. 2 weeks is way too much for that crap. i just downgraded to 5.3.1 which seem to work fine